# Позиции модулей как в Joomla

Tags: php

Как можно сделать на своем самописном сайте позиции модулей?
Например, есть блок <div></div> 
Внутрь блока прописываю {left}, и вместо этого туда вставляются модули в позиицей left

Answer (score 1):

По сути, вы хотите написать шаблонизатор. Ну, раз вы любите велосипедить, то ищите статьи в гугле, используя запросы аля "[пишем свой шаблонизатор php](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Пишем+свой+шаблонизатор)", "[как сделать шаблонизатор php](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=как+сделать+шаблонизатор+php)" или что-то в таком роде. Только зачем, если готовых шаблонизаторов пруд пруди?

Comment: а в двух словах объяснить тяжело? а-то я не знал, что есть гугл